# Pre-commit SVN Hook + image optimization script

Tags: svn, optimization, image-processing

I was wondering if anyone had tried to make a pre-commit SVN hook to "smush" images before the commit using SmushIt, PunyPNG or any optimization script.

I tried looking on google but looks like nobody ever tried to do this.

I need advices and/or feedbacks.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Pre-commit hooks should not modify the transaction that is about to be committed. From the [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks):

> While hook scripts can do almost
>   anything, there is one dimension in
>   which hook script authors should show
>   restraint: do not modify a commit
>   transaction using hook scripts. While
>   it might be tempting to use hook
>   scripts to automatically correct
>   errors, shortcomings, or policy
>   violations present in the files being
>   committed, doing so can cause
>   problems. Subversion keeps client-side
>   caches of certain bits of repository
>   data, and if you change a commit
>   transaction in this way, those caches
>   become indetectably stale. This
>   inconsistency can lead to surprising
>   and unexpected behavior. Instead of
>   modifying the transaction, you should
>   simply validate the transaction in the
>   pre-commit hook and reject the commit
>   if it does not meet the desired
>   requirements. As a bonus, your users
>   will learn the value of careful,
>   compliance-minded work habits.

A safer alternative would be to simply check images in the pre-commit hook, and refuse the commit if the criteria are not met. (You could still have a "smushing" script in your project and committers would just have to remember to run it manually before each commit that involves images.)

If you are sure you really want to modify commits on the fly, you might still be able to do it safely on the client side. For example, TortoiseSVN has [client-side hook scripts](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks).

Answer (score 1):

I'll admit, I'm not exactly answering the question, but I'm trying to steer you down a better path.  You really shouldn't mess with the content of commit in the start-commit or pre-commit hooks.  Besides, wouldn't you like to have the original unaltered graphic in the repository so in case the "smush" operation ruins the images or is not to your liking, you can always get the original back out of the repo and edit it again?

Now in your case, what I'd suggest is to setup a post-commit script that would detect that a graphics file has been committed and then call your "smush" tool if the image doesn't meet certain criteria (size, etc).  Once the image has had a "smush" applied to it, then commit it back to the repository.